# ¿Por qué recibo un objeto vacío en el req.body de la petición si estoy usando body-parser?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, postman, microservices

Estoy haciendo una práctica de microservicios con node básicamente esta es la estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es tener 3 microservicios, uno de libros, otros compradores y otro de ventas, pero ahora estoy trabajando solamente en el de libros.

Pero por alguna razón el body del request lo recibo vacío aunque estoy utilizando bodyparser:

en código básicamente solo tengo esto:

books.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('this is the bookst route')
} )

app.use(require('./routes/books.routes'))


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/msbooks', 
{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, ()=>{
    console.log('connected to mongo db');
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('running on http://localhost:3000/')
})
```

y books.routes.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const Book = require('../schemas/books.schema')


app.get('/books', (req, res) => {
    res.send('books endpoint works')
})

app.post('/books', (req, res) => {
    // const {title, author,  page, publisher } = req.body

    console.log(req.body);

   return res.json({
      ok: ':)'
    })
})

module.exports = app
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero siempre me aparece vacío

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sospecho que es por el custom type que añades `bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' })`. Si no añades el header `Content-Type: application/*+json'` cuando haces la petición no te lo va a parsear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada te recomiendo que solo pongas
`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Segundo:

El `Content-Type` de la `request` debe ser `àpplication/json` para que `bodyParser` construya el `req.body` de otra manera lo deja vacío.

Answer (score 0):

la libreria `express.js` esta evolucionando constantemente, es por eso que [desde el 2017](https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c) (la version 4) se incluyo a `body-parser` dentro de esta. El uso de `body-parser` solo esta para mantener proyectos de legado.

Te muestro la forma en la que activas el modulo correspondiente

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// y coloca esto antes de usar middlewares o rutas
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

...
module.exports = app
```

De esa manera puedes recibir datos con `req.body` o responderlos con `res.json()`